# Can I set the TTL for documents loaded into Couchbase from HDFS using Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, couchbase, sqoop, ttl

I am attempting to load a JSON document from Hadoop HDFS into Couchbase using [sqoop](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.html).  I am able to load the documents correctly, but the TTL of the document is 0.  I would like to expire the documents over a period of time and not have them live forever.  Is that possible with the Couchbase connector for Sqoop?

As I said, the documents are loaded correctly, just without a TTL.

The document looks like this:

```
key1@{"key": "key1", "message": "A message here"}
key2@{"key": "key2", "message": "Another message"}
```

The sqoop call looks like this:

```
sqoop export -D mapred.map.child.java.opts="-Xmx4096m" \
             -D mapred.job.map.memory.mb=6000 \
             --username ${COUCHBASE_BUCKET} \
             --password-file ${COUCHBASE_PASSWORD_FILE} \
             --table ignored \
             --connect ${COUCHBASE_URL} \
             --export-dir ${INPUT_DIR} \
             --verbose \
             --input-fields-terminated-by '@' \
             --lines-terminated-by '\n' \
             -m 2
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's a straightforward UI/settings to do it. The code would have to be modified within the connector.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TTL option in the current sqoop plugin version. However, if you just want to set the same TTL for all the imported objects, you can quite easily add the code yourself. Take a look at line 212 here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-hadoop-plugin/blob/master/src/java/com/couchbase/sqoop/mapreduce/db/CouchbaseOutputFormat.java#L212

You just need to add a TTL parameter to the `set` calls. If you want to be thorough about it, you can take the TTL value from the command line and put it in the DB configuration object, so you can use it in code.